# optimize MySQL self join query with different where and order

Tags: mysql

[edited]

Goal is to subtract the value of a field (somevalue) in a certain order based on sequential field (sequentialsortfield) using a self join. The query as-is gives the correct result however with large datasets is very slow. Using mysql 'explain' shows this query is not using index but rather filesort although all three example fields are indexed. If I remove the 'order by' it no longer uses filesort [but] does not yield the correct result in terms of desired order.

I have searched and seen nothing on SO or MySQL docs that has helped.  Can't seem to avoid `using filesort` on table1 unless I drop the `order by` but I do need it.  Index's exist on all three fields.

Have generified the example to illustrate my question.

Structure for "table":

```
id                    INT  
somevalue             INT  
sequentialsortfield   INT
```

Query:

```
select table1.somevalue-table2.somevalue as PrevRowDiff 
FROM table AS table1, 
table AS table2 
WHERE table1.sequentialsortfield+1 = table2.sequentialsortfield 
order by id;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do.. can you explain yourself better?

Comment: subtract the value of a field in a certain order using a self join.  The query results in the correct result however with large datasets is very slow.  Using mysql 'explain' shows this query is not using index but rather filesort.  If I remove the 'order by' it is optimized but does not yield the correct result in terms of desired order.

Comment: are there any additional condition? Or you are going to dump the whole large dataset?

Comment: This is basically it.  Its part of an import where I need to straighten out a mess then do some row over row calcs after establishing the correct row order.  Like I said, the query works as is but it's both bothering me that I can't seem to fully optimize it - and sometimes takes minutes to complete.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually rather tricky to make this query efficient. Long story short, you neeed to force MySQL to output data in the primary key order when you have a covering index on `sequentialsortfield` (which you anyway need for the join to be efficient).

I would suggest creating two composite indexes and try to implicitly force one of them:

Say,

```
ALTER TABLE the_table ADD KEY the_one_to_force (id, sequentialsortfield, somevalue);
ALTER TABLE the_table ADD KEY usual_one (sequentialsortfield, somevalue);
```

And rewrite the query as following (you do not need an ORDER BY in this case):

```
SELECT t1.somevalue-t2.somevalue as PrevRowDiff 
FROM the_table t1 FORCE INDEX (the_one_to_force)
JOIN the_table t2 ON t1.sequentialsortfield+1 = t2.sequentialsortfield
```

The idea is that the data will be read in the order of the `the_one_to_force` index and output data if there is a match (as it actually happens anyway, but the appropriate indexes are chosen by the MySQL optimizer based on the query).

Comment: Sounds logical I'll give this a shot and update shortly - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Select table1.somevalue-table2.somevalue as PrevRowDiff 
FROM table AS table1
Join table AS table2 
on table1.sequentialsortfield+1 = table2.sequentialsortfield 
group by sequentialsortfield
order by id;
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt.  This results in "Using temporary; Using filesort" vs original just "Using filesort".